# Draw D3.js graph inside dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I have this (probably weird) setup where I'm ajax'ing a template of sorts into a section of my page, and then trying to draw a chart with D3.js inside one of the elements of that template.

Weirdly, sometimes it renders, others it doesn't, complaining about what I figure out must be the element which holds the chart not being rendered at that moment, as it's coming from an ajax call.

How can I overcome this? I've been reading about jQuery's `when()` and `then()` but I can't seem to grasp how it might (if at all) help me in my case.

This is a (simpler) version of my code:

```
$.get("/url/to/my/template", function(templateData){
    // this element is already in the page
    $("#elementInThePage").html(templateData);
    // this function draws the D3 chart
    buildChart();
});

function buildChart(){
    // this element comes in the template
    // sometimes it's already available, other times it isn't
    // and obviously d3 complains about it not being there
    var element = d3.select("#elementInTemplate");
    // do more stuff (...)
}
```

To sum it up, how to be sure I only call `buildChart()` when `#elementInTemplate` has rendered?

**EDIT:** I already tried chaining `.done()` to my `$.get`, but exactly the same thing happens.

**EDIT2:** I think I mis-explained my problem. D3.js doesn't complain about it not being there. What actually happens is that it is drawing the chart conditionally in regard to the size (WxH) of the element in the template, and because that element still hasn't rendered, it borks up the chart.

**EDIT3:** Another (relevant, I think), note: in `buildChart()`, D3.js depends of the dimensions of the template's element. So, if I

```
console.log($("#elementInTemplate").width()+" x "+$("#elementInTemplate").height());
```

If it fails, I get `234 x 0`. If it works I get `234 x 456`.

Comment: So this line : $("#elementInThePage").html(templateData);, renders elementInTemplate ? and once you have ran this line you want to call buildChart() only when its finished running ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy yes, that's it. I believe that will help me fix this issue. Although I would like to stay away from setting timeouts and stuff like that and was rather wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ I think these should help you

Comment: @thisOneGuy because I don't want it to *only* work if there is a width and height. I want it to *always have width and height so that it works*.

Comment: just use a variable width and height and overwrite them if you can update both width and height with the new dimensions, if not use the old width and height (or default) then use these values in the D3

Comment: @Joum Could you provide an example which helps reproducing the effect?

Comment: @altocumulus unfortunately, no I can't. I tried setting up two JSBins for this (one with the template, other with my code) but couldn't actually make it fail like my local dev version fails.

Comment: @thisOneGuy that would make sense, unfortunately, I can't fallback on default values because my layout has to be responsive, so there won't be a catch-all scenario.

Comment: so how will you know the width and height you can't get them from the generated area ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy It's set using relative dimensions, ie, %, in CSS. I don't need to know the dimensions, but D3 needs to be able to get them so that it can draw the chart. But if if the container isn't rendered before it tries to get those dimensions, it borks.

Comment: if its set, then I dont see the problem in getting the dimensions ? Have you tried using plain javascript rather than jquery ? So clientHeight or offsetHeight ?

Comment: And you've made sure to only start rendering when the document is ready (i.e. https://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: @rmoestl I think that doesn't make sense in my case, because I'm trying to render *after* I append new elements to the DOM (which are coming from the template). What I need, in fact, is to have the new elements *"ready()"* so I can then call my render function.